# Deploying Jboss war fails

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have Jboss 7.1.1.Final installed, and am trying to deploy a war located in standalone/deployments. The deployment with the same war is fine on my colleagues' computers, but fails on mine.

Any idea would be nice! Here's my web.xml: http://textuploader.com/1oam. Here's the log (full log: http://textuploader.com/1oaq):

```
10:19:24,387 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-5) JNDI bindings for session bean named SNAConsoleConfiguration in deployment unit deployment "sna-app-gwt.war" are as follows:

    java:global/sna-app-gwt/SNAConsoleConfiguration!es.gsyc.sna.server.SNAConsoleConfiguration
    java:app/sna-app-gwt/SNAConsoleConfiguration!es.gsyc.sna.server.SNAConsoleConfiguration
    java:module/SNAConsoleConfiguration!es.gsyc.sna.server.SNAConsoleConfiguration
    java:global/sna-app-gwt/SNAConsoleConfiguration
    java:app/sna-app-gwt/SNAConsoleConfiguration
    java:module/SNAConsoleConfiguration

10:19:24,619 WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2
10:19:24,619 WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan.providers found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2
10:19:24,620 WARN  [org.jboss.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011204: resteasy.scan.resources found and ignored in web.xml. This is not necessary, as Resteasy will use the container integration in the JAX-RS 1.1 specification in section 2.3.2
10:19:24,628 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 3.0)
10:19:24,633 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.1)
10:19:24,636 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
10:19:24,724 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) Cannot create permissions with 'null' metaData for id=sna-app-gwt.war
10:19:24,727 INFO  [es.gsyc.sna.server.SNAConsoleConfiguration] (MSC service thread 1-5) Load SNA Console configuration:
{sna.persistent.service.debug=true, sna.persistent.hadoop_conf_dir=/var/apps/socam}
10:19:24,743 INFO  [org.imdea.networks.socam.sna.engines.utils.EngineUtils] (MSC service thread 1-5) uploading engine XMLs
10:19:24,749 ERROR [org.imdea.networks.socam.sna.engines.utils.EngineUtils] (MSC service thread 1-5) /content/sna-app-gwt.war/WEB-INF/lib/SNA-graph-engines-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar (No such file or directory)
10:19:24,749 INFO  [org.imdea.networks.socam.sna.engines.utils.EngineUtils] (MSC service thread 1-5) the following engines were found: []
10:19:24,754 ERROR [org.imdea.networks.socam.sna.engines.utils.EngineUtils] (MSC service thread 1-5) cannot store hadoop M/R lib: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content/sna-app-gwt.war/WEB-INF/lib/Hadoop-1.3.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.imdea.networks.socam.sna.engines.utils.EngineUtils.uploadXMLs(EngineUtils.java:88) [SNA-graph-engines-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at es.gsyc.sna.server.SNADataManager.init(SNADataManager.java:86) [classes:]
    at es.gsyc.sna.server.SNAConsoleConfiguration.init(SNAConsoleConfiguration.java:49) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:130) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:112) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:333) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.SingletonLifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonLifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:56) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:116) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:130) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService.start(ComponentStartService.java:44) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

10:19:24,769 ERROR [es.gsyc.sna.server.SNAConsoleConfiguration] (MSC service thread 1-5) Unable to parse configuration file at initialization: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot store hadoop M/R lib
    at org.imdea.networks.socam.sna.engines.utils.EngineUtils.uploadXMLs(EngineUtils.java:95) [SNA-graph-engines-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at es.gsyc.sna.server.SNADataManager.init(SNADataManager.java:86) [classes:]
    at es.gsyc.sna.server.SNAConsoleConfiguration.init(SNAConsoleConfiguration.java:49) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:130) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:112) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:333) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.SingletonLifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonLifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:56) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:116) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:130) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService.start(ComponentStartService.java:44) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content/sna-app-gwt.war/WEB-INF/lib/Hadoop-1.3.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.imdea.networks.socam.sna.engines.utils.EngineUtils.uploadXMLs(EngineUtils.java:88) [SNA-graph-engines-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    ... 39 more

10:19:24,908 FATAL [org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions] (MSC service thread 1-8) The scratchDir you specified: /usr/local/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.bak/standalone/tmp/work/jboss.web/default-host/sna-app-gwt is unusable.
10:19:24,919 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /sna-app-gwt
10:19:24,922 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) Qualified url patterns: {/=PatternInfo[pattern=/,type=3,isOverridden=true,qualifiers=[PatternInfo[pattern=/*,type=1,isOverridden=false,qualifiers=[]]]], /*=PatternInfo[pattern=/*,type=1,isOverridden=false,qualifiers=[]]}
10:19:24,923 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) Dropping overridden pattern: PatternInfo[pattern=/,type=3,isOverridden=true,qualifiers=[PatternInfo[pattern=/*,type=1,isOverridden=false,qualifiers=[]]]]
10:19:24,929 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
10:19:24,930 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 8448ms - Started 365 of 445 services (79 services are passive or on-demand)
10:19:25,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "sna-app-gwt.war"
10:19:52,015 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011503: Restored bootstrap log handlers
10:19:52,021 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/] has not been started
10:19:52,023 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
10:19:52,024 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
10:19:52,065 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032018: Destroying TransactionManagerService
10:19:52,065 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032014: Stopping transaction recovery manager
10:19:54,141 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] JBAS015877: Stopped deployment sna-app-gwt.war in 2137ms
10:19:54,143 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 2138ms
```

Thanks,

Philippe

------------------ EDIT

I found the solution, I was linking the war in standalone/deployments instead of linking the exploded war (the folder next to it ending in SNAPSHOT).

Comment: Can you include your web.xml?

Comment: Moreover, make sure that the WAR that you exported contains following JARs int the lib folder. "SNA-graph-engines-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar" "Hadoop-1.3.jar"

Comment: Thanks for your answers, this is my web.xml: http://textuploader.com/1oam
And yes, the war contains these two jars. Furthermore, it deploys just fine on my colleagues' machines.

Comment: Rather than put the answer in the question (where no one will find it), actually answer your own question and "accept" that answer (which is perfectly fine to do). Also remove "solved" from the title. Having an accepted answer *means* it's solved. Don't stress - I did exactly the same for my first question as you have done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was linking the war in standalone/deployments instead of linking the exploded war (the folder next to it ending in SNAPSHOT).